# Least Squares and Preconditioners

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

I've seen the preconditioned least squares objective function $\arg\min_{x}\Vert P^{-1}Ax-P^{-1}b\Vert_2$, where $P^{-1}$ is positive definite.  However, I'm not sure how we show that this is the equivalent to the original $\arg\min_x \Vert Ax-b\Vert_2$.  My attempt is that if $\sigma$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $P^{-1}$, then
\begin{align}
\sigma\Vert Ax-b\Vert_2 \leq \Vert P^{-1}Ax-P^{-1}b\Vert_2 \leq \Vert P^{-1}\Vert  \Vert Ax-b\Vert_2
\end{align}
and noting that $\arg\min_x \sigma \Vert Ax-b\Vert_2=\arg\min_x \Vert P^{-1}\Vert \Vert Ax-b\Vert_2$, we have
\begin{align}
\arg\min_x \Vert Ax-b\Vert&=\arg\min_{x}\Vert P^{-1}Ax-P^{-1}b\Vert_2
\end{align}
but I'm not sure that this argument is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not equivalent to the original one, essentially now you are minimizing with respect to another inner product, the one given by $\langle x , y\rangle := xP^{-T}P^{-1}y$. Up to an orthogonal transformation this is a weighted least squares for some weights $w_1,\dots, w_n$, hence this is not equivalent to the original minimization (no weights).

Comment: Thanks.  I was wondering about this, but I see from p 312 of https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PS/iter3.pdf that they use the normal equations derived via the objective function I mentioned, and here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971189/preconditioning-the-damped-normal-equations-reference they mentioned the same objective function.  Is there some assumption from each of them I'm missing?  I actually implemented the first one and it gives the same results as solving for least squares.